# Can a woman be a zadik?

Tags: halacha, history, women, tzaddikim

Can a woman be a zadik?  Who of the matriarchs would be considered a zaikai if women can be.  Thank you.

Comment: Can you define Tzaddik in this context?

Comment: Voted to close as unclear, in agreement with DoubleAA's question. The term has numerous nuances. See my comment to the answer, for details. If you like the answer, perhaps, edit the question so that the term "tzaddik" is unambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

Of course a woman can be a *tzaddik*, which just means a righteous person. (Though grammatically the term would technically be "*tzadeket*" since that is the feminine form of the word.) All the matriarchs and heroines of scripture and Rabbinic writings are traditionally considered "*tzadikim*". In fact, the first *mishna* in *Perek Chelek* of Tractate *Sanhedrin* invokes the verse (Isaiah 60:21) "Thy people also shall be all righteous (*tzadikkim*), they shall inherit the land for ever; the branch of My planting, the work of My hands, wherein I glory." to indicate that "All Israel has a share in the world to come..." (whether male or female). Non-Jews who accept and are careful to keep the 7 Noachide commandments are also considered righteous and merit a share in the World to Come, again without regard to gender (and, in fact, are even called "*hassid*" [pious]; see, e.g. Maimonides' Mishna Torah The Laws of Kings 8:11).

Comment: I don't argue with your conclusion itself. But, I'm not sure that some of the sources cited provide a definitive answer. My question would be what does one need to do to become a "tzaddik". DoubleAA questions this point, as the term has a certain nuances that OP didn't specify. The Isiah verse just says that every Jews is a tzadik, automatically. So, does that mean s/he doesn't need to do anything at all? Rambam's comment seems irrelevant to this as it seems that since the OP mentioned Sarah, he may be concerned only about a Jewish viewpoint. Also, a "Hasid" does not necessarily imply a tzadik

Comment: A tzadik is much more than just a righteous person. Tanya discusses it

Comment: I heard a rabbi preach that a tzaddik is  reightous with deep spiritual understanding.Not just someone doing good stuff.